# Permanent access to public facebook group events with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I am creating a website that has a calendar module. Calendar should download the events from Facebook group. I have no problems when downloading events from Facebook Page - App Access Token is enough and it doesn't have valid date. But for groups Facebook acts kind of weird:

- To get public group posts I need app access token, no problem
- To get public group events I need user access token.

User access token is a huge problem because it has max 60 days valid time.  Nobody will come and reauthorize with Facebook to get new token every 60 days in case of this website, website is to be static and whole "active content" must be taken from the Facebook, without anyone accessing website backend.

Does anyone get around this problem? Use some external service that renews its token and generates some sort of feed? Any other way?

Does Facebook really require us to write some sort of bots to scrap the events from the public group?

Comment: scraping is not allowed, and auto-refreshing the user token is not possible.

Comment: If you are doing it server-side, then you don’t need an access token for every website visitor, but only one - f.e. yours. Can _you_ be bothered to go and refresh your access token every 60 days maybe …? If not, then the whole thing resp. the website probably isn’t not that important after all.